# pip install torch がエラーになる

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

プログラミング初心者かつ、初質問です。
Pythonでプログラムを書いたところ、`import torch` の行でエラーになり、`pip install torch` を行おうとするとエラーになります。virtualenv などのアンインストールを行いましたが治りませんでした。以下、エラー文です。

```
pip install torch torchvision
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3xdeqzsh/torch/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3xdeqzsh/torch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9sdh6knp
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-3xdeqzsh/torch/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9sdh6knp/torch.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9sdh6knp/torch.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9sdh6knp/torch.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9sdh6knp/torch.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9sdh6knp/torch.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9sdh6knp/torch.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: package directory 'torch/cuda' does not exist
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: MacOSのようですが、Pythonの版数とか環境(Anaconda/Miniconda)が合っていますか？ ちなみにWindowsの素のPython3.9ではインストール出来ず、3.8では出来ました。3.9は未だサポートしていないかもしれませんね。

Comment: pytorch公式からコピペしてインストールしてはいかがですか？  
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally